# Visual Studio 2008 Create new Smart Device project option not available

Tags: visual-studio, project, smart-device

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 (also tried with 2010 beta) and cannot see the option to start a new smart device project (for windows mobile)

I have tried multiple websites - I appears I have to install windows mobile 6 SDK but when I try to install that it says I need to have visual studio 2005 installed.

Am I missing something really obvious?  I have installed on several PCs and don't see any options for visual studio to install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart Device development is only supported in the Professional Edition or better.  If you're running Express or Standard, you won't have the Smart Device projects.

Comment: That explains why it doesnt show up in vs2008.  I have 2010 ultimate beta installed on my work pc and it doesnt show there either.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 doesn't support Smart Device development; the announcement for that is a bit cagey on when (or if) it's coming: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I am not going crazy after all. (about this anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If you have VS 2008 Professional Edition installed but still encountered installation error, then this is the solution http://guruce.com/blogpost/installing-ce-60-sdks-on-systems-with-only-vs2008-installed

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the remind.sorry this is my first comment. Thanks again.